# Android application to post SMS as HTTP

Tags: android

I am thinking of developing an android app, that would be sending sms as a http to a web application.

I am new to android, so am not sure if there's such an API or maybe the best way to handle this task. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: would you only developing the android app or also the web-page?

Comment: I would be developing the web page too which would accept the parameters posted from the android app and send them to a databse @Boe-Dev.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about doing the same, until I found out about [SMSSync](http://smssync.ushahidi.com/). It works great and it's free software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, but I was also in need of this kind of Android app. Here's my findings:

- [SMSsync](http://smssync.ushahidi.com/) (already [mentioned by @bjesus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11619975/1252290)): handles SMSes only. Latest commit February 2017
- [cht-gateway](https://github.com/medic/cht-gateway) (formerly medic-gateway): part of a product but can be used independently. Handles SMSes only. Latest commit March 2022
- [EnvayaSMS](http://sms.envaya.org/): handles SMSes, MMSes and calls. IMHO the one with the most features. Tested on Android 8. Latest commit April 2012
- [Telerivet Gateway App](https://telerivet.com/product/app): EnvayaSMS' successor

Answer (score -1):

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();  
List<String> divideContents = smsManager.divideMessage(content);    
for (String text : divideContents) {    
    smsManagersmsManager.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, text, sentIntent, deliveryIntent) ； 
}
```

Comment: Have you read the Question..`sending sms as a http to a web application`